# Is there a special 3/32" chain ring for single speed/fixed gear bikes?

Tags: chainring, fixed-gear, single-speed

Am I able to use what's called an "Outer" chain ring in a single speed application?  Something like this

https://www.modernbike.com/sugino-48t-110mm-standard-chainring

Thank you.

Comment: "No ramps or pins" usually means singlespeed ring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3/32 chainrings made specifically for single speed use, but chainrings intended for double cranks will work just fine if they fit your crank properly and are on the correct chainline of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By "correct chainline", you mean insure the cog and chain ring are aligned? Could using the wrong chain ring throw this out of whack and if so what measurements on the chain ring are associated with this alignment?

Comment: 'you mean insure the cog and chain ring are aligned?' Exactly. some chainrings are essentially made from a flat plate, but some are more '3D' and offset the attachment points slightly inward.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks